# hidesBarsOnSwipe disables Left & Right Swipe Gesture

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, swift2

As in my code below, when I add the `hidesBarsOnSwipe` property, my swipe left and right functions are somehow disabled and start not to work. how to  make them all work at the same time?

```
 let leftSwipe = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("handleSwipes:"))
 let rightSwipe = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("handleSwipes:"))

  leftSwipe.direction = .Left
  rightSwipe.direction = .Right

  view.addGestureRecognizer(leftSwipe)
  view.addGestureRecognizer(rightSwipe)

  self.navigationController?.hidesBarsOnSwipe = true
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        var leftSwipe= UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "respondToSwipeGesture:")
        swipeRight.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Left
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(leftSwipe)

        var rightSwipe= UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "respondToSwipeGesture:")
        swipeDown.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Right
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(rightSwipe)

        self.navigationController?.hidesBarsOnSwipe = false
        self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated:   true)
 }

    func handleSwipes(gesture: UIGestureRecognizer) {

        if let swipeGesture = gesture as? UISwipeGestureRecognizer {
            switch swipeGesture.direction {
                case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Right:
                    print("Swiped right")
                case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Left:
                    print("Swiped left")
                default:
                    break
            }
        }
```

Comment: Hi 13th Ghost, It did not changed, in your code hideBarsOnSwipe = false, I want to use that funcionality, so I set it as true, but when I do this, the left and right swipe functions do not work.